# How to recursively grep the pattern inside the directory?

Tags: vim, grep, vimgrep

I would like to grep all string patterns which are start with the:
    **student_**
, then
    **any  numbers of symbols(letters and digits)**
and end with the
    **.tcl**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep "student_[[:alnum:]]*\.tcl" *
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're using vim 7, it comes with a build in grep function that puts the result in a quicklist-window.

try

```
:vimgrep /^student_/ **/*.tcl
```

`**` makes the search recursivelly

To search in current directory only, use:

```
:vimgrep /^student_/ *.tcl
```

read more @ [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim)

Comment: As far as I understand  this reg-exp  search pattern   inside files that have .tcl extensions?  Is it ? But I would like search in all the files insed directory.

Comment: try it out. It searches recursively from current directory all files ending with .tcl and containing the string student. To search in current directory only, just use *.tcl. See updated answer

Comment: wouldn't you want a backslash before the dot so as not to match any character?

Comment: +1 for the vim answer!  If someone wants to see how it worked or just got too many result in quickfix window, check the Gif here : https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep. :D :D